# Transaction Amount Changes After Confirmation

Tags: paypal

Really bizarre this one - getting same results in live environment and sandbox environment.

Process:

1. Simple e-commerce site sends a single amount, description, quantity, to PayPal for payment.
2. PayPal displays the correct amount in left hand column
3. Log in with developer account and select valid credit card
4. Confirm that the currency exchange is correctly providing the amount in the new currency (USD) from the provided currency (NZD)
5. Complete payment and return to website

All of that works BUT for some reason the confirmation email - and in the live environment case the actual payment - has now treated the original amount LESS 15% which is the tax rate for the original currency.

Completely stumped. Kind of hoping there is a simple setting I have to flick OR perhaps another variable to send through to PayPal when I get the token to stop this from happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being in touch with PayPal support it turns out the bug was indeed at my end. Here is their explanation:

> The reason why you do see different
>   amounts is because your shopping cart is sending a different value
>   within the SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckout requests.
>
> Within the SetExpressCheckoutRequest, the amount sent is "258.75".
>   This value is just an estimation made by your shopping cart for the
>   total transaction amount, it can change later. PayPal sends you back
>   the same value within the GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse, but when
>   your site makes the last request (DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest),
>   the amount sent to PayPal is "225.00" instead.
>
> Therefore, your shopping cart is implementing some logic between
>   GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse and DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest
>   that you are not aware of.

Does seem a bit odd to me that you would display one price to the customer but then potentially charge them something completely different - though I'm sure there is a very good reason for this.